# Wordpress curl login error

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, authentication

```
<?php
$username = "";
$password = "";
$url = "https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php";
$cookie = "cookie.txt";

$postdata = "log=".$username."&pwd=".$password."&rememberme=forever&wp-submit=Log+In&redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.com%2F&testcookie=1
";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "https://wordpress.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwordpress.com%2F");

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;

exit;


?>
```

am unable to login to wordpress using curl php this is the error i am getting 
"ERROR: Cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress."

Answer (score 0):

Use full path (i.e. `/var/abc/cookie.txt`) instead of just file name.

Also use option `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE`  along with cookiejar.

Comment: $cookie = "C:\xampp\htdocs\curllogin\cookie.txt";  curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);  and still not working.

Comment: Use `/` instead of `\\`. And also make sure your apache has write access on that file.